# scanning an array to pick a random string from it

Tags: java

I have a text file and I want to randomly pick a string out of there. Have some code, but it doesn't work properly

```
File file = new File("name.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    Random random = new Random();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] s = {line};
        int select = random.nextInt(s.length); 
        System.out.println(s[select]);
```

if I do so it prints the whole file without any random method. Have I missed something?

Comment: `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("name.txt")); System.out.println(random.nextInt(lines.size()));`

Comment: Do this exercise: before each line of code, by helping you of the javadoc, write as a comment what the line of code does. If the line of code initializes a variable, write what the value of the variable becomes.

Comment: What is `films`? And you do realize that `s` is always an array of exactly one element, right? So `s.length` is always 1, `select` will always be 0, and `s[select]` will always be same as `line`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to pick a line at random you have 2 choices :

- Read the entire file in an array of lines, then use a random function to pick one ;
- Read one line at a time, and use a random function to decide if *this line* is the chosen one. For example, use `random.nextInt(100)` to draw a number from 0 to 99, then if that number is less than 10, choose that line (10% chance). If the file runs out of lines before a line is picked, you can either revert to solution #1 (because you now have read all the lines), or just pick the last line read (it avoids storing all the previously read lines).